# Does calling .Result on a task that has already been awaited break the async pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, async-await

By the time the code calls `Task.Result`, it has already been awaited, so does the asynchronous pattern here still hold?

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var addNumbersTask = AddNumbers(10, 20);

        var result = AwaitForResult(addNumbersTask).Result;

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    static async Task<int> AddNumbers(int a, int b)
    {
        await Task.Delay(250);
        return a + b;
    }

    static async Task<int> AwaitForResult(Task<int> task)
    {
        await task;

        return task.Result;
    }
}
```

Background if you're interested: Trying to emit IL code for a proxy class that needs to handle async calls, but I don't want to generate the async state machine in the IL. So I figured I could delegate the actual "await" part to a helper outside of the IL. Also, I know there are proxy types out there but the hopeless engineer in me wants to write it myself.

Edit: Updated example.

```
interface IService
{
    Task<int> AddAsync(int a, int b);
}

class Service : IService
{
    public async Task<int> AddAsync(int a, int b)
    {
        await Task.Delay(250);  // Some web service call...
        return a + b;
    }
}

// This class 100% generated via reflection emit
class Proxy : IService
{
    private readonly IService _actual;

    public Proxy(IService actual) => _actual = actual;

    public Task<int> AddAsync(int a, int b)
    {
        return Awaiter.Await(_actual.AddAsync(a, b));
    }
}

static class Awaiter
{
    public static async Task<int> Await(Task<int> task)
    {
        return await task;
    }
}

class Program
{

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var proxy = new Proxy(new Service());
        var result = await proxy.AddAsync(5, 5);

        Console.WriteLine($"Result is {result}", result);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does the asynchronous pattern here still hold"?
Calling the `Task.Result` after the task has already been awaited is generally fine, but what you're doing in your example code is calling it in the main thread over the Task that is created by `AwaitForResult`. So you will have some code executing in parallel, but you won't be taking any advantage of that, because your main thread will be blocked, waiting for the task to complete.

Comment: By asking if the pattern still holds, I'm trying to determine if the method will execute asynchronously. You pointed out that my `Main` method is blocked because it must wait for the task to complete, so the result is "no, this will not completely execute asynchronously" and I consider the async pattern broke. If I modified the `Main` method to `var result = await AwaitForResult(addNumbersTask);` would that resolve the blocking?

Comment: Good rule of thumb when using async/await: just don't use `.Result`.

Comment: In general, yes. By using `await` you make the calling thread return instead of block, and whatever should happen after the `await` is called will happen in a callback, after the task is completed, asynchronously. What is important to note here is the traditionally, the `Main` function can't be asynchronous (can't contain any `await`s). This makes sense, when you think of it, because you need the main thread of your program to stay alive, not to return (causing your program to exit). Since C# 7 you can have an `async Main`, but that's compiler magic, in the end, the main thread will be blocked

Comment: Thanks @NimrodDolev, I updated my question with a more practical example of what I'm trying to (generating a proxy class).

Comment: The usage of async/await in the updated example is correct. I would add that some of the wrappings you're doing are redundant, but I understand from the original question that there is a purpose for all these layers. Either way, purely regarding asynchronicity, I don't see a problem with your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does the asynchronous pattern here still hold?

No. There's nothing magical about using `await` on a task. Instead, consider *whether the task is completed*. Calling `task.Result` will block the calling thread until `task` completes. Doing `await task` will asynchronously wait until `task` completes.

So in this code, `Result` will not block:

```
static async Task<int> AwaitForResult(Task<int> task)
{
  // Task may not yet be complete here.
  await task;
  // At this point, task is complete.

  // Since task is complete, Result does not block.
  return task.Result;
}
```

But that is totally different than this code:

```
var result = AwaitForResult(addNumbersTask).Result;

// Equivalent to:
var task = AwaitForResult(addNumbersTask);
var result = task.Result;
```

The task returned from `AwaitForResult` may not be complete here, since it was never `await`ed. And if it's not complete, then `Result` will block.

> Trying to emit IL code for a proxy class that needs to handle async calls, but I don't want to generate the async state machine in the IL. So I figured I could delegate the actual "await" part to a helper outside of the IL.

Have you tried Roslyn APIs? I find them much more convenient than IL emit.

If your proxy is just a pass-through, then you can just return the inner task directly:

```
// This class 100% generated via reflection emit
class Proxy : IService
{
  private readonly IService _actual;

  public Proxy(IService actual) => _actual = actual;

  public Task<int> AddAsync(int a, int b) => _actual.AddAsync(a, b);
}
```

But if you want to add much real logic, then I'd recommend using Roslyn to generate the `async` state machine for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re trying to avoid blocking, then no.

In your console app example it makes little difference, but if you did that somewhere where you don’t want blocking - e.g. a UI event handler - `.Result` will still block.

By the time you have a value in `addNumbersTask`, that task is started. You then immediately pass the task to `AwaitForResult`, which immediately begins to await it, at which point an *incomplete* task that returns an `int` is returned back to `main()`, and you then call `.Result` on it. You are now blocking that thread for most of the 250ms until that task returns its `int` result to `.Result` in `main()`.

The way you have expressed it in the question, “awaited” does not equal “completed”.

Answer (score 0):

The method `Awaiter.Await` is basically pointless.  Outside of adding some overhead, the returned task will be functionally identical to the one passed in.

The only actual difference in code between simply returning the result of `_actual.AddAsync(a, b)` and awaiting it is that, if `AddAsync` throws an exception, if the method is `async` it will return a faulted task instead of throwing.  So if that either can't happen, or if `Proxy.AddAsync` can safely throw itself in that situation, then simply return the value, no need to do anything.  If you need to ensure that `Proxy.AddAsync` never throws an exception, and instead returns a faulted task if `Proxy.AddAsync` throws an excpetion, then you simply need to wrap the method in a `try/catch` and return a faulted exception in the catch block.  You don't need to replicate any of the rest of the logic of the `async` state machine.

So assuming you want the same exception semantics as the behavior of the service's method, which I suspect you do, you can treat these methods exactly the same as you would a synchronous method, that is to say invoke the method with the appropriate parameters and return the result.